# C# Project - How to use two third-party DLLs with conflicting redistributable dependencies

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, dll, redistributable

I have a C# service than needs to use two DLL libraries from two different vendors.  Source code is not available for these libraries.  The libraries perform separate functions.  Each library requires Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable to be installed, but they require different versions.  Is it possible to use both of these libraries within my service at the same time?  Is there a way to specify where each third-party DLL looks for and loads its dependencies, for example by file location or other app.config configuration?  I don't know enough about the .NET CLR, when dealing with DLLs and there dependencies to know how this is handled.

Comment: Yes. every dll has a full path that includes the parent namespace.  So you just have to add the namespace to select the correct dll.  The include statements at top of a modules is the names spaces of the libraries like System.Net.Sockets where System.Net is the namespaces and Socket is the class library.

Comment: Remark: the .NET CLR has nothing to do with the resolution of unmanaged DLL (like the MSVC redistributables) references.

Comment: @jdweng But the question is about different versions of the *same* DLL. Namespaces will not help here.

Comment: I recommend not trying to do this.  It's fraught with risk, getting into edge cases that are undefined in documentation/specifications.  You might be able to get something to "work," but you won't know why or for how long :(

Comment: I got this to work without a problem.  I had an issue with the child sub-dependencies of one of the DLLs which C# confusingly reported as an exception of the parent DLL not being found.  Tracing the inner exception chain led me to the culprit.